# Npm prefix -g not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, npm

So, idk why this happening and how to solve too. I read some posts and tried to change the PATH in environment variables but it doesn't work for me (or i just did wrong). And i put an image on below showing my problem.

Thats its my variables now. (none have ";" ahead)

> **User Variable:**
>
> JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.11\bin\javaw.exe
>
> SEE_MASK_NOZONECHECKS = 1
>
> TEMP = %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
>
> TMP = %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
>
> Path = % PATH%;
> C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts;C:\User\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft
> VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\
>
> **System Variable:** (Not everything)
>
> ComSpec = C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291
>
> Path = C:\Program Files\nodejs
>
> PATHEXT = .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more details, have you installed NPM with Windows installer? `.msi` or `.exe` file is easier to install that downloading it since it adds npm to your environment variables. Also did you try running the `npm --version` command to check the output? Although it doesn't make a difference but try it just in case.

Comment: I installed using windows installer ```.msi``` file, and i did ```npm -v```, thats its my image content